# Warning - does not implement the 'collection' pattern

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable, compiler-warnings

I am making collection, implementing `IEnumerable` explicitly and trying to iterate it from within:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { yield return default(T); } // test

    public void Test()
    {
        foreach (var item in this) { } // here is warning
    }
}
```

I get compiler warning at `this`:

> Warning   CS0279  'MyCollection' does not implement the 'collection' pattern. 'MyCollection.GetEnumerator()' is either static or not public.

Hell yes, it's not public. Why it should be? I **can** make it public, but it's not needed for `foreach` outside of type:

```
foreach (var item in new MyCollection<string>()) { } // no warning
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just call it something else? `GetEnumeratorImpl`? Or just don't use explicit interface implementation for `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator?`

Comment: @JonSkeet, so it's only name confising compiler?

Comment: Yes - because the pattern-matching in `foreach` *finds* the `GetEnumerator()` method, but can't then use it. Adding an answer now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning exists because the C# compiler can handle `foreach` in a number of different ways. One of those ways is to find a `GetEnumerator` method with a suitable return type. That's checked *before* the compiler checks whether or not the type of the expression implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

In your case, it gets as far as finding the single parameterless `GetEnumerator` method, but it's not public. The C# specification recommends a warning at this point, as you may well have *intended* it to be usable for `foreach`. From the C# 5 spec, section 8.8.4, emphasis mine:

> - Perform overload resolution using the resulting method group and an empty argument list. If overload resolution results in no applicable methods, results in an ambiguity, or results in a single best method but that method is either static or not public, check for an enumerable interface as described below. **It is recommended that a warning be issued if overload resolution produces anything except an unambiguous public instance method or no applicable methods.**

Any of the following would solve the problem:

- Rename `GetEnumerator` to `GetEnumeratorImpl` or similar:

  ```
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumeratorImpl();
  IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumeratorImpl();
  IEnumerator<T> GetEnumeratorImpl() { yield return default(T); }
  ```
- Don't use explicit interface implementation for `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` - put the implementation there

  ```
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => { yield return default(T); }
  ```
- Put the implementation in `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`, but cast `this` to `IEnumerable<T>` in `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` to call it:

  ```
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<T>) this).GetEnumerator();
  IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() => { yield return default(T); }
  ```

Comment: Second option is the most cleanest I think. My obvious mistake was to implement both interface explicitly, only one has to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See the explanation for compiler warning  CS0279 here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz2286x8(v=vs.90).aspx

> **There are several statements in C# that rely on defined patterns, such
>   as foreach** and using. For example, **foreach relies on the collection
>   class implementing the enumerable pattern**. This error occurs when the
>   compiler is unable to make the match due to a method being declared
>   static or not public. **Methods in patterns are required to be instances
>   of classes, and to be public**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Not the point. Read about [explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) interface implementation. External `foreach` doesn't need any explicit method to be public. In fact you **can not** make explicit implementation public